I cant compile boost beast example "http_server_async_ssl.cpp"
Using linux ec2, I want to compile the boost beast example file:
boost_1_86_0/libs/beast/example/http/server/http_server_async_ssl.cpp (SSL)
What I CAN do is compile http_server.cpp which is a web server (but plain http) by going to that dir and typing:
c++ http_server_async.cpp -I /home/ec2-user/boost_1_86_0 -o server -pthread
But... the difficulty lies with the http_server_async_ssl.cpp file using openssl.
Openssl was actually already installed in the aws ec2. But what I need is the include files for openssl that are referenced in http_server_async_ssl.cpp and generating compile errors or where to find them on the machine (I have tried searching) or on the web (again I have tried searching, and downloading, extracting openssl, but still no luck...)
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
Please note this is not a duplicate of a question about compiling the plain http server example...

The steps I gave you yesterday work for this as well:
Unable to find/use bjam in linux ec2
Assuming a clean ubuntu server docker container:
docker run --rm -i -t ubuntu

Installing the minimum system
apt update
apt-get -yy install build-essential wget libssl-dev
wget https://archives.boost.io/release/1.86.0/source/boost_1_86_0.tar.bz2
tar xf boost_1_86_0.tar.bz2 
cd boost_1_86_0/
./bootstrap.sh 

Linking b2 into the path for convenience:
mkdir -pv ~/bin
ln -sfv "$PWD/b2" ~/bin/
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"

It builds just fine:
cd libs/beast/example/http/server/async
b2

Pudding + Proof:

No B2/Bjam?
Then you need the extra options for

include paths to find example/common headers
the linker inputs for libssl

g++ -I /boost_1_86_0/ -I /boost_1_86_0/libs/beast/http_server_async_ssl.cpp -lssl -lcrypto

Proof + Pudding:

